# Euler products, Merten's theorems, and an unexpected result

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, twin-primes, euler-product

I'm going to start by saying I'm mostly out of my depth here. I'm an amateur recreational mathematician. But I've been looking at the Twin Prime Conjecture lately, because it is *so* fascinating. Easy enough for an 8-year-old to understand, but perplexing mathematicians for millennia. As a science teacher, the whole preponderance-of-empirical-evidence thing seems reasonable enough... but of course, not for mathematicians.

I have no delusion I'll *prove* anything, but maybe I can contribute something useful? And I have a weird result that may or may not be useful, that I also can't explain.

In relation to the TPC, I've been working on a sieve that generates [This OEIS sequence](https://oeis.org/A002822), the numbers for which $6k \pm 1$ are both prime. I'm trying to build off of the work of [Dinculescu's](https://benthamopen.com/ABSTRACT/TOMATJ-5-8) various papers (one linked, others at the OEIS link). The TPC is the conjecture that this sequence is infinite.

What does this have to do with Euler products? I've been working with the following one:

$$\prod_{5 \leq p \leq n} \left(1-\frac2p\right)$$

Simple enough. It starts at 5 because it's looking at twin primes, and has a 2 in there because the sieve removes $\frac2p$ of $\mathbb{N}$ each pass.

There are [a lot of constants that can be calculated using Euler products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_product#Notable_constants). The one I'm working with above isn't one of them, or even similar. So I poked around a bit. Merten's 3rd theorem says this:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\ln n\prod_{p \leq n} \left(1 - \frac1p \right) = e^{-\gamma}$$

This theorem seemed interesting to me because the Euler product portion is basically the leftovers in $\mathbb{N}$ after $n$ iterations of the Sieve of Eratosthenes. As $n \to \infty$, the "leftover" set is just $\mathbb{P}$. So, the Sieve of Eratosthenes diverges to zero (as we'd expect since the density of $\mathbb{P}$ is zero), but when multiplied by $\ln n$, it converges. That's a pretty cool trick!

For the heck of it, I tried multiplying the iterations of my product by $\ln n$ to see what came out, which was still divergence to zero, uninteresting. So I looked at [Hardy and Littlewood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime#First_Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_conjecture) and noticed their constant ends up with an $(\ln n)^2$ term when calculating $\pi_2(n)$. Since my product diverges to zero about twice as fast as Mertens's, I decided to try that out, and I got something that converged! And I tried to figure out if the value it converged to ($\approx 2.49726$) was a known constant. After some trial and error I found:

$$\lim_{n \to\infty} (\ln n)^2 \prod_{5 \leq p \leq n} \left(1-\frac2p\right) \approx 4\lambda$$

Where $\lambda$ is... the Golomb-Dickman constant, something I'd never heard of. (This is by empricial computer calculation only, but it converges to four digits with about 6 million primes.) Apparently $\lambda d$ is the (asymptotic) average number of digits in the largest prime factor a $d$-digit integer.

But! We come around full circle. The *complement* of that OEIS sequence is the subset of $\mathbb{N}$ for which $6k \pm 1$ are not twin primes. These are all the natural numbers of the form $6ab \pm a \pm b, 1 \leq a \leq b$. That fact was discovered by.... [Solomon Golomb](https://oeis.org/A002822/a002822.pdf).

I have exactly zero clue as to whether what I've written here is particularly useful. I certainly can't *explain* it. But at least to me, it's pretty interesting. Has anyone here worked with this sequence, and the TPC, and might have an explanation for what seems like it's maybe just a cosmic coincidence? Is this a new result, or am I chasing rabbits others have already chased?

(Edited (1): Typo in the numerical result. After ~6M primes, my value has converged to $2.49726$, *not* $2.49276$. Only correct to four digits, not five.)

(Edited (2): Gerry Myerson, in the comments, helpfully pointed out a reference that contained the product I was looking at, though starting at 3 rather than 5.  It turns out that my original product converges to $12C_2e^{-2\gamma} \approx 2.497287$, which just happens to be very *very* **close** to $4\lambda \approx 2.497320$. The $0.0013%$ difference between the makes them easy enough to confuse when you don't know what you're approaching asymptotically.)

Comment: According to Finch, Mathematical Constants, Section 5.4, the Golomb-Dickson constant is $\lambda=0.62433$ to five decimals, giving $4\lambda=2.49732\ne2.49276$.

Comment: In Section 2.1, Finch gives $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\log n)^{-2}\prod_{2<p<n}{p\over p-2}=1.20130356=(0.83242907)^{-1}$, rounding to eight decimals. Note this starts with $p=3$, not $p=5$.

Comment: Oh, that was a typo. I currently have 2.49726, not 2.49276.  So it's only correct to 4 decimal places currently. I believe $\gamma$ converges similarly slowly if you try to calculate it from Mertens's theorem.

Comment: That second limit from Finch ($0.8324...$) is in fact $\frac13 = \frac{3-2}{3}$  of the value $2.49726$, to four digits.

Comment: Does Finch give a context for the calculation of that product?

Comment: Oh interesting, thanks Google books.  Apparently the (reciprocal) value is in fact $4C_2 e^{-2 \gamma}$, and just happens to be *close* to 4/3 of the Golomb-Dickman constant. That's perhaps even more interesting.

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to follow up on this briefly, in case anyone was actually watching it. I found the reasoning for the constant given in Finch. First, we take all of the infinite products involved and start them at 3--rather than at 2 (Merten's 3rd theorem) or 5 (the product I was working with). H&L's $C_2$ already starts at 3. Then we have these, assuming $ 2 < p < n $ for all products:

$$C_2 = \prod\left({\frac{p(p-2)}{(p-1)^2}}\right) =\prod\left({\frac{p}{p-1}}\right) \cdot\prod\left({\frac{p-2}{p-1}}\right) \tag 1$$
$$\frac{2e^{-\gamma}}{\ln n} \sim \prod\left({\frac{p-1}{p}}\right) \tag 2$$

Then multiplying $(1)$ by $(2)$ (leaving behind equality but keeping asymptotic notation):

$$C_2\frac{2e^{-\gamma}}{\ln n} \sim \prod\left({\frac{p-2}{p-1}}\right) $$

If we multiply by $(2)$ a second time, we get:

$$C_2\frac{4e^{-2\gamma}}{(\ln n)^2} \sim \prod\left({\frac{p-2}{p-1}}\right) \cdot\prod\left({\frac{p-1}{p}}\right) = \prod\left({\frac{p-2}{p}}\right) $$

$$C_2\frac{4e^{-2\gamma}}{(\ln n)^2} \sim \prod\left({1-\frac2p}\right)$$
which is the result given by Finch, and the result I was looking for in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

The connection between Euler's totient function
$$\phi(n)=n\prod_{p|n} \bigg(1-\frac{1}{p}\bigg)$$
and your formula
$$n\prod_{5\le p \le n} \bigg(1-\frac{2}{p}\bigg)$$
is $\to$ both are '**emptiness calculating formulars**'.

This example [PHI(105)InGeneralDivisorPlane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8uI4.jpg) shows the 48 resulting values of $\phi(105)$ in the 'general divisor plane':

$\to$ If all numbers divisible by $3, 5$ and $7$ are excluded, 48 '**empty lines**' remain (here 'filled' as green parallels).

In my answer to this [Why is the twin prime conjecture hard?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3755850/why-is-the-twin-prime-conjecture-hard) post I argued, that in the 'special divisor plane for twin primes', where $y$ is $n \equiv 0 \pmod 6$, this also 'emptiness calculating formula'
$$y\prod_{(x \equiv 0 \mod 6)\pm 1} \bigg(1-\frac{2}{x}\bigg)$$
represents a lower bound for twin primes (since including non-prime x-values leads to an underestimation of twin primes).

By the way, lower bounds for prime quadruplets etc. can also be constructed using the same approach.

I'm always surprised that the structures that exist in $\Bbb Z$ are usually not visualized using divisor planes !?

Comment: I hadn't heard of a divisor plane before. What is that chart supposed to show? I understand the lines dx and the labeling of divisors as points, but how is it calculating the totient? And what's up with the quadratic in the bottom right?

Comment: Yes, divisor planes are not yet known where they can visualize so much so easily. You get the totient of 105 = 3 * 5 * 7 = 2/3 * 4/5 * 6/7 = 48. ALL green lines together are the resulting 48 lines. And the green lines (= natural numbers) are solutions because they are neither divisible by 3, nor by 5 or 7, so to say fill the 'horizontal emptiness' between divsor points in the 'x-columns' 3, 5 and 7. Twin primes can be counted in the same way --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/LK5Gb.jpg

Comment: If you are interested in the parabolic properties of the general divisor plane  --> https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faktorisierungsmethode_von_Fermat#/media/Datei:Fermat's_factorization_in_the_divisor_plane.gif